How to setup EPiServer(Optimizely) CMS 9 sample site
I want to setup EPiServer(Optimizely) CMS 09 sample site. Since the latest EPiServer version is CMS 12, I was not able to setup CMS 09 sample site.
CMS 12 is using the .net templets to install new sample site.
The older version used the EPiServer CMS extension.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EPiServer.EpiserverCMSVisualStudioExtension
This extension is also upgraded and now support only CMS 11.
Any idea how to setup CMS 09 sample site ?
Tried to use the older version of EPiServer CMS extension(CMS 09 version)
